# postgres table looks broken

Tags: postgresql, psql

My postgres looks really streng suddenly and I do not why! What are those pluses and dashes? The table is create via liquebase in spring. It looked normal before. Now my get requests are not working and I am not sure if it is relevant to this schema problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.9.xsd">
    <changeSet id="create_questionnaire_entity_11" author="Iman Gharib">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="questionnaire_entity"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="questionnaire_entity" schemaName="public">
            <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="patient_number" type="varchar"/>
            <column name="questionnaire_id" type="varchar"/>
            <column name="received_date" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="question_type" type="varchar"/>
            <column name="question_text" type="varchar"/>
        </createTable>
        <addPrimaryKey tableName="questionnaire_entity" columnNames="id"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="extend_text_size_2" author="Iman Gharib">
        <modifyDataType
                columnName="question_text"
                newDataType="varchar(2000)"
                tableName="questionnaire_entity"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

select * from the table:

```
  id  | patient_number |      questionnaire_id       |      received_date      | question_type |      

                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                               question_text    

------+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That is the row separator between the column headings and the table. You have a wide `question_text` column and your pager is wrapping the lines rather than clipping them and letting you scroll left and right.

Comment: Take a look at `\pset` and its `format` section  here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).  You might try in `psql` `\pset format wrapped`.